# Publish Google Apps Script as a Web App vs. publish it as a Service

Tags: google-apps-script

In [Google Apps Script Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) I found class [Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_service) and it has `enable()` method which "Enables the script to be published as a service". My question is: what's the benefit of publishing script as a service, how is it different from publishing it as a web app? It's not clear from the reference.

I'm guessing a service is not supposed to have a UI in contrast to a web app, however I can create a web app without UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are one and the same. The old "Publish as service" terminology is replaced by "Publish as Web app". In the context of Google Apps Script, a Web app is the same as a service. A web app can have a UI (UIApp or HTMLService) or it may just serve text or JSON (ContentService).

Refer to the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/release_notes?hl=en) for June 18, 2012 where it states "Publish > Publish as service is now Publish > Deploy as web app."

The Service class lets you do the publish actions programmatically and can be used for example, to provide your users with a good install experience. Here's a link to the announcement with example code http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com.au/2012/04/introducing-script-service.html

Comment: Thanks Peter, but I still don't understand, what's the point in having the Service class functionality.

Comment: I have added some explanatory info for you.